# Sort the data in mongo collection based on Timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection containing following fields:

```
{
            "key" : "21",
            "first_seen_on" : 1513689319.47154,
            "name" : "",
            "id" : "STOREBOX",
            "file_id" : "211",
            "app_name" : "FB"
        }
```

I have to write a query that sorts my data based on the `first_seen_on` field. I plan to get the count of number of records seen in last 24 hours. 
I looked around quite a bit around converting the time format into a readable format and then split the date part. I am fairly new to mongo so it was easy to get lost. The best help was from this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/hlr6XsB24SM
But I am still far from an actual functional query. 
Would be great if anyone from this community can help me out with the query.

Comment: are you using pymongo (mongo driver for python) on your machine ?

Comment: you can easily write a code to sum all of the value in a field , I'm knowing this  , if you want the solve , tell me to code it for you.

Comment: No need to convert. Try `db.colname.count({"first_seen_on":{$gte:24 hours back timestamp, $lte:right now timestamp}})`

Comment: @Veeram great. This helped. Though it gives me one day data, I can create a small script now and get a week data. is there a way I can do this operation directly from the query?